# Load data from previous run

Tags: android, persistent-storage

I'm pretty new in this so I need some help.

I want to load data from previous run. To be more precisely, some lets say "coins" (Integer)  will be given to user on app install. During play he will gain and lose some of them and now I want user to countinue with the same amount on next run.
What should I do now?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Shared Preferences to store a key value pair

```
//Get a reference to SharedPreferences for your app
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("my.app.packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Store your value
int coins = 10;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("coins", coins);
editor.commit();

//Retrieve your value on a subsequent run
//The 0 is the default value of coins, if it is not yet defined.
int coins = sharedpreferences.getInt("coins", 0);
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: ok ok, i've made it with sharedpref :) and know how to use :D ty

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Shared preferences to do this task.

```
SharedPreferences reference= getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = reference.edit();
editor.putInt("Key",mSnowDensity);
editor.commit();

//To retrieve
SharedPreferences reference= getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
int snowDensity = reference.getInt("Key", 0); //0 is the default value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shared preference to store the data, you can retrieve the data on the app later. This is one of many methods to persist data on Android

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences